# MS Outlook to Office365 file format migrate with tool How does migrate MS Outlook to office365?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I used first-time tool but this tool is not properly working, its convert only 5 folders in one time. I have many folders please suggest me how convert all file in one time.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if email accounts are configured in Outlook client, we can directly export items to a PST file via File > Open & Export > Import/Export. And then import the PST file back to your Office 365 account.
Reference:

[Migrate email and contacts to Office 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/setup/migrate-email-and-contacts-admin?view=o365-worldwide)

[Export or backup email, contacts, and calendar to an Outlook .pst file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-or-backup-email-contacts-and-calendar-to-an-outlook-pst-file-14252b52-3075-4e9b-be4e-ff9ef1068f91)